# Weird symbol under my character after [Empty] was equipped

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was climbing the road to the shrine of Azura, south of Winterhold. At the top of the road, there was a frost troll. As the road is very steep, I decided to Fus Ro Dah his ass and watch him faceroll to his death downhill, which is what happened. But then something unexpected happened. As soon as my Fus Ro Dah landed on the frost troll, it was written " was equipped" at the top left corner of my screen. I guess I must have equipped Nothing... but what is Nothing? I don't know. at the exact same time I looked down only to see i was walking on some weird blueish transparent icon thing that is indefinitely emitting a frostbite-like spell effect (it's stuck under my legs and it doesn't go away, whatever i try to do). I can't properly describe what the weird blueish transparent icon thing looks like because it is self-aware and seems to be shape shifting everytime I look at it from a different angle.

My question is pretty simple: What the hell happened?

I don't know if that frost troll is always there, but let me quickly enumerate the steps to reproduce the event.

1. Have Unrelenting Force level 3
2. Approach the said frost troll (at the top of the road leading to the shrine of azura)
3. Fus Ro Dah his ass and watch him faceroll to his death downhill.
4. " was equipped"
5. Forever ride a mysterious blueish transparent icon thing
6. ???
7. Profit

Images:
[image: Icon]
[image: Riding the icon]

Other images:

- [image 1: location](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/595830338364707674/AD2FA02E965D0C915D1D83B17665A93CEDCC8F72/)
- [image 2: troll](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/595830338364705419/6937A4EFDA2BCCA2AD69BD54408DC76E21B0BA2A/)
- [image 3: fus ro dah](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/595830338364701822/28C874BC4032D96846D8FD47342201695A3FF2F0/) (" was equipped" at the top left corner of this image)

Comment: If you can't describe it, post (or link to because of your low rep) a picture.

Comment: added images...

Comment: The icon in your picture looks like an Ice Wraith!?  Did you equip an Ice wraith? :)

Comment: @GmNoob yes, that looks like a ice wraith that's stuck in the ground.

Comment: if anyone else tried this out, I'd like to know. And if it doesn't work, maybe i could share my save file to prove I'm not crazy, but maybe I am crazy.

Comment: Assuming you are playing on the PC. What mods do you have installed? Maybe one of your mods are messing up the game?

Comment: @JonasSöderström no mod at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is what solved it for me:

Open console, type:

```
player.addspell 000CAF8A
```

Close console and open it again. Type:

```
player.removespell 000CAF8A
```

[Source thread on Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?s=31ec11e37dbba8e1108168d269fc4ddc&p=26535823&postcount=6)

Answer (score 0):

Check under Active Effects to see if there is an effect listed that explains what you're seeing.

Comment: I have, and there's nothing more than what I usually have there